Min cost perfect matching, but with conflicting edge pairs
Consider the following variant of min-weight perfect matching. We are given a graph $G = (V,E)$ with non-negative weights on the edges. We are also given a collection of pairs of edges $P \subseteq E \times E$.
Each of these pairs represents a pair of edges which are not allowed to be simultaneously included in the solution. In other words, in addition to having degree 1 on every vertex, our matching $F \subseteq E$ must not include both edges from any pair in $P$.
We seek to find a minimum weight solution satisfying these constraints. This problem is NP-hard (see here). But I am looking for approximation algorithms. Are any known to your knowledge?
I would be happy for any results, even in the case that the conflict graph is a collection of isolated edges.

If you allow arbitrary conflict graph then it seems that you can capture maximum weight independent set  (MWIS) as a special case and we cannot approximate MWIS.

If the conflict graph has good approximation for MWIS via certain restricted class of rounding algorithms then one can obtain a similar guarantee when you combine it with the matching constraint. The basic idea is to use contention resolution schemes. I am going to refer to a paper of mine but it is not the right reference for this special case but better than nothing. https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4593
